# VBA - Excel VBA Set Horizontal & Vertical alignment

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have created a click event that allows me to add a colour to two different cells. However, at the moment, it only sets the colour to the cells vertically.

I am desperately trying to find a option to allow users to select whether they want to add the colours vertically or horizontally. This is how my code looks thus far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()

Dim chemin1 As Object
Set chemin1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J10")
With chemin1
Dim length As Integer
Dim ship As String
Dim message_box As String

length = 1

message_box = "Vertically or Horizontally?"

If message_box = "V" Then
        length = length + 4
        Do While length > 0
        length = length - 1
        ActiveCell.Interior.color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
        ShipCount = ShipCount + 1
    MsgBox "Your ship has been placed."
ElseIf message_box = "H" Then
{ Do the same but horizontally }
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you the `Application.InputBox()` method to prompt the user to select 4 cells where they want to place the ship.

```
Dim rngSelected As Range
Dim sSelectedAddress As String

Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngSelected = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select 4 cells vertically or horizontally where you would like to place your ship.", Title:="Place Ship", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rngSelected Is Nothing Then
        If rngSelected.Rows.Count > 1 And rngSelected.Columns.Count > 1 Or Not rngSelected.Cells.Count = 4 Then
            MsgBox Prompt:="Your selection must be 4 cells within the same column or 4 cells within the same row."
            Set rngSelected = Nothing
        Else
            rngSelected.Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
            MsgBox Prompt:="Your ship has been placed."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox Prompt:="Canceling ship placement."
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop While rngSelected Is Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a yes/no msgbox but usually an input box is required for input values. Such as.

```
    Dim chemin1 As Object
Set chemin1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J10")
With chemin1
    Dim length As Integer
    Dim ship As String
    Dim message_box As String
    message_box = InputBox("V or H")

    If message_box = "V" Then
        ActiveCell.Range("A1:A5").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
        MsgBox "Your ship has been placed."
    ElseIf message_box = "H" Then
        ActiveCell.Range("A1:E1").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    End If
End With
```